# Creating a method in Service class to get data from Repository in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to create a method that return list of all users of a specific role. I have different method in the Service class like findUserByName, etc, but when I try to find list of users using the role property it does not work. I do have role defined in the User model.

User model:

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your user name must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a user name")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your last name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

}
```

Role model:

```
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "role")
    private String role;
}
```

User Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    private UserRepository userRepository;
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                       RoleRepository roleRepository,
                       BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public User findUserByUserName(String userName) {
        return userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    }

    //method to find user by role
    public List<User> findUsersByRole() {
        return ;
    }


    public User saveUser(User user, String role) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        user.setActive(true);
        Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole(role);
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<Role>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

Role repository:

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
    Role findByRole(String role);

}
```

User Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    User findByEmail(String email);
    User findByUserName(String userName);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to write a query in `UserRepository` to use the ManyToMany User-Role association:

```
List<User> findByRolesId(Long id);  // using here ID of the role
```